# Facebook-Instagram api is missing metrics from /stories/insights: actions( sticker taps, swipe ups) & if the story is made up of multiple media

Tags: instagram-graph-api

The instagram app allows you to see the following metrics for /story/insights: (notably interactions: swipe and sticker taps) see image 
[image]

Meanwhile the facebook instagram api only gives access to metrics: impressions, reach, taps_forward, taps_back, exits, & replies.
[reference here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights)

It is not giving access to missing data on the story/insights endpoint, how would one go about accessing?

As well, if a story is made up of multiple images/video/media, say 10 panes, how does one separate the metrics per pane within a story?

Comment: Hi, have you managed to find a way to get sticker taps, link clicks etc from the API or otherwise?